# Button clicks count as pageviews

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

My client has a single page website and want each click on the main menu for a site area count as a pageview in Google Analytics. Is this possible? I advised him to use events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, call _trackPageview in JavaScript.

```
_trackPageview()

_trackPageview(opt_pageURL)
Main logic for GATC (Google Analytic Tracker Code). If linker functionalities are enabled, it attempts to extract cookie values from the URL. Otherwise, it tries to extract cookie values from document.cookie. It also updates or creates cookies as necessary, then writes them back to the document object. Gathers all the appropriate metrics to send to the UCFE (Urchin Collector Front-end).

Async Snippet (recommended)
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview

Comment: No, you can call this function to record your own action. It's often used with single-page AJAX-based applications.